# Nativescript - native android bluetooth low energy

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, nativescript, android-bluetooth

I am wondering why I can't access native android bluetooth low energy in Nativescript, yet I can access native android classic bluetooth.

```
const adapter = android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
```

The sample code above works fine, while the sample code below does not work.

```
const BleAdvertiser = android.bluetooth.le.BluetoothLeAdvertiser;
```

Error: "Property 'le' does not exist on type 'typeof bluetooth'"

Does anyone know why that is? Any help is highly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Which version of Android device you are using for testing?

Comment: @Manoj android version 9.0

Comment: It's accessible on my end, tested with Playground in Android v8.1.0.

Comment: @Manoj all right, thank you very much for your help. I will try to figure it out again.

Comment: @Manoj Are you using android studio?

Comment: As I already mentioned I tested with NativeScript Playground.

Comment: @Manoj Oh right, I'm sorry. My mind's running in circles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem!

For anyone who might encounter the same problem, go to your references.d.ts file which is in your project folder which should contain something like

```
/// <reference path="./node_modules/tns-platform-declarations/ios.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="./node_modules/tns-platform-declarations/android.d.ts" />
```

Then update your android.d.ts file which should contain something like

```
/// <reference path="./android-17.d.ts" />
```

Change 17 into at least 21, these numbers represent API Levels. Android native bluetooth low energy is supported in API level 21 or Android v5.0 (Lollipop).